# FRONT END - jBox?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, aplicação-web

Como ou o que usar para fazer um  efeito em que o usuário perceba que a tabela minimizou até aquela pequena tabelinha ? Por exemplo: O efeito de minimizar do MAC ...
No momento apenas existe uma relação de Fade e Hide, como pode-se ver nas imagens a seguir.

Agradeço a colaboração de vocês :D

Site: http://carboncal.org.br/view/brasil
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe mais de um efeito ao minimizar uma janela no Mac.
Dois comuns são o [Genie Effect](http://www.site.uplabs.com/posts/modal-interaction-with-genie-effect) e [Scale Effect](http://hawkee.com/snippet/16154/).

No caso do Scale Effect eu não achei um bom pronto, mas com o exemplo que linkei é possível adaptar para minimizar ao invés de sumir.

Comment: Hum.. parece bem adaptável. Obrigado Daniel ! :D

Comment: Nessa situação eu escolheria o Genie Effect, porque gosto mais do efeito e porque já está pronto. Qualquer dúvida na implementação deles no seu sistema pode falar aqui.

Comment: Não da pra implementar pois usa o plugin do GreenSock. Parece que é pago :/ Se puder dar uma ajuda rs

Comment: Putz, realmente... Eu vou tentar procurar outra versão do Genie, mas o [Scale](http://codepen.io/Hawkee/pen/ogbqjV) só usa jQuery e Bootstrap.

Comment: Também estou procurando, enquanto isso estou fazendo outra atividade rs Vida de estagiário hehe'